# Getting hadoop cluster information from within a job

Tags: java, azure, hadoop, mapreduce

I am writing a hadoop job that should collect the start and finish times of all jobs that ran in a cluster, and upload this data to a blob. However, I'm not sure how to get this information, as a job doesn't seem to have access to the job tracker. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of [getLaunchTime()](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobInProgress.html#getLaunchTime%28%29) and [getFinishTime()](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobInProgress.html#getFinishTime%28%29) methods provided by the Class [JobInProgress](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobInProgress.html). The API also has a [JobTracker](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobTracker.html) Class that provides [getJobsFromQueue(String queue)](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobTracker.html#getJobsFromQueue%28java.lang.String%29) method that can be used to get all the jobs submitted to the particular Queue.

Apart from these methods these classes also have some other very useful methods which you might find helpful.

HTH